# How to write a function that takes a variadic number of array<double, N> and deduce N?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

The goal is to have a function that takes an arbitrary number of array<double, N> of arbitrary size N (but this can be the same for all), and have N available inside the body of the function. For example let's say I want to return another user defined array type using N, MyArray<N>. I hope it's more clear! Thanks I am new to variadic templates and don't know how to do this. Any help or tip is appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<int N>
struct MyArray {};

// here I don't know how to deduce N and keep the variadic number of parameters

template<int N, typename... Ts>
MyArray<N> foo(const Ts&... ts)
{ 
  // somehow use the variadic parameters
  MyArray<N> a;
  return a;
}

int main()
{
  array<double, 3> a, b, c;
  auto d = foo(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: @Scheff `N` should be the size of the arrays given as arguments, not the number of arrays. The code shown should only deal with `std::array<double,3>`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, the goal is to have a function that takes an arbitrary number of array<double, N> of arbitrary size N (but this can be the same for all), and have N available inside the body of the function. For example let's say I want to return another user defined array type using N, MyArray<double, N>. I hope it's more clear! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, the still bad element is that the type of N in the template part of Foo has to match exactly the type used in std::array to indicate the size, this makes N known inside and can be used to make a MyArray object.

Basically I had to declare the parameter pack a template (thus having a template with a templated pack). Ts... is there because array normally takes more than 2 template parameters.

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<int N>
struct MyArray {};

template<typename T, long unsigned N, typename... Ts, template<typename, long unsigned, typename...> typename... Arrays>
MyArray<N> Foo(const Arrays<T, N, Ts...>&... arrays)
{
    return MyArray<N>{};
}

int main()
{
    array<double, 3> a, b, c;

    MyArray<3> d = Foo(a, b, c);
    auto e = Foo(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand what your function is trying to do. I guess it's "sum all the arrays and add N to each field", if it's not, my example should be a good illustration regardless.

```
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
std::array<double, N> foo(std::array<double, N> first)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    first[i] += N;
  }
  return first;
}

template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
std::array<double, N> foo(const std::array<double, N>& first, Ts&... ts)
{
  std::array<double, N> result = foo(ts...);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    result[i] += first[i];
  }
  return result;
}

template<size_t N>
void print_array(const std::array<double, N>& arr) {
  for (double x : arr) {
    std::cout<<x<<" ";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
}

int main() {
  std::array<double, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};
  std::array<double, 3> b = {4, 5, 6};
  std::array<double, 3> c = {7, 8, 9};
  auto d = foo(a, b, c);
  print_array(d);
  d = foo(a, b);
  print_array(d);
}
```

Comment: Note that `main` is required to have the return type `int` in C++. It is not allowed to be `void`.

Comment: I have corrected my question and made it clear I hope, I'll try to work on your solution, thanks a lot, recursion is the only way then?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can accept a sequence of `std::array`, deducing the dimensions, and SFINAE enable the function only if the dimensions coincide.

I mean... something as

```
template <std::size_t N0, std::size_t ... Ns,
          std::enable_if_t<((N0 == Ns) && ...), int> = 0> 
auto foo (std::array<double, N0> const & a0,
          std::array<double, Ns> const & ... as)
 { 
   std::array<double, N0> d;
   d[0] = (a0[0] + ... + as[0]);
   d[0] += N0;
   return d;
 }
```

or also

```
template <std::size_t ... Ns, std::size_t N = (Ns + ...)/sizeof...(Ns),
          std::enable_if_t<((N == Ns) && ...), int> = 0> 
auto foo (std::array<double, Ns> const & ... as)
 { 
   std::array<double, N> d;
   d[0] = (N + ... + as[0]);
   return d;
 }
```

Or, if you prefer, deduce the first size and impose the following types are the same

```
template <std::size_t N0, typename ... Ts,
          std::enable_if_t<((std::is_same_v<std::array<double, N0>, Ts>) && ...), int> = 0> 
auto foo (std::array<double, N0> const & a0, Ts const & ... as)
 { 
   std::array<double, N0> d;
   d[0] = (a0[0] + ... + as[0]);
   d[0] += N0;
   return d;
 }
```

As pointed by François Andrieux, instead the SFINAE way you can follows the `static_assert()` way, to get a more meaningful message error

```
template <std::size_t N0, std::size_t ... Ns> 
auto foo (std::array<double, N0> const & a0,
          std::array<double, Ns> const & ... as)
 { 
   static_assert( ((N0 == Ns) && ...), "some clear error message!");

   // ...
```

but, this way, you can't develop different and alternative versions of `foo()`.

See you what solution is more useful for you.

Comment: It may be more useful to put the verification for the array sizes in a `static_assert`. The error message would be more meaningful.

Comment: did anybody notice the funny bug when a post gets edited and the hat is still shown in its old position?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Well... I usually prefer the SFINAE way, because you can add alternative version of `foo()`... but who knows the OP needs? Added the `static_assert()` alternative.